# Language switcher doesn't work with my views

Tags: views

I am new to this forum, but I hope to get an answer to my problem. Searching 2 days already, bur no success...

I have a multilingual (French and Dutch) D7 website. Besides the needed core modules enabled, I installed the [i18n](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) module and the variable [i18n](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) module. As for normal pages, everything works perfect. I have a menu for each language, the menu links refer to the correct pages. I have also a language switcher, which works perfect with my nodes.

Now comes my problem. I created a view to display a teaser of all products. Look at http://www.solarine.eu/solarine/ to see what I mean. I made a view for the Dutch language (called "producten"), and one for the French ("produits"). When you access the pages by the main menu, they display correcly (5 products for Dutch, only 1 for French). BUT if you use the language switcher to toggle between languages when visiting the products page, the content of the views stays in the wrong language.

Can anyone please help me with this? It MUST be possible to solve this, but after 2 days searching on different websites with no result, I am out of ideas.

Many thanks!
Steven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to solve this with Views, here is how:

1. Go to your view's edit page.
2. Add a Filter Criteria called 'Content translation: Language'
3. In the popup that comes after that, select 'Current user's
   language'
4. Save the Filter Criteria and your view as well.

After this, this view will only show items that are the same language as the language you are using at the moment on the website.

You can however set a specific language to your view as well with the same criteria. You just have to select a language instead of 'Current user's language' and that view will only list content that are in that specific language.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. However, I don't see that specific filter in my list. In the content translation set, I have only "Source translation", "Translation set node ID" and "Translation status". Neither of these give the wanted result. Tryed that before :(

Comment: Are you sure you have all neccessary modules enabled for multilanguage sites? Like the Content Translation core module? Even if it's not that module, I'm pretty sure there is a i18n module that should be enabled for that criteria to show up.

Comment: Following modules related to multilingual websites are enabled: Content translation, Locale, variable, i18n, views i18n. Maybe there is some setting wrong. Is that possible? Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Try enabling the Multilingual content and Multilingual select modules in i18n as well and check Views Filter Criterias again. I'm still suspecing that one of the i18n modules should be enabled for this, because I never had to update any settings in order to use this criteria and I've build a lot of multilingual Drupal sites.

Comment: All submodules in i18n are enabled, except for forum translation, as there will be no forum on the website. The 2 modules you speak of, are surely enabled. Can it be that there is a problem with the language switcher?

Comment: I found it! I am working with the Dutch version of Drupal, and the criteria are filtered in another way than in the English version. Very confusing. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @Steven Same issue i am facing can you share where you found the solution.

Comment: I made a taxonomy tree with a language specified for each item. In a new content type, I added a taxonomy-type field. In my view, I put selection criteria "Taxonomy list: system name" and I selected my taxonomy list. Second filter: "Taxonomy term: language" with "Language of the current user". I hope this will help you.